# Simplification of expression involving sums of cubed variables

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

I have a problem to understand a solution:

The solution is:

$E(m)=\Sigma_{k=1}^{13}(1-\frac{k-1}{13})^3$
$=\frac{1}{13^3}\Sigma_{k=1}^{13}k^3$
$=\frac{1}{13^3}(\Sigma_{k=1}^{13}k)^2$

I do not understand how they got from the first line to the second line not from the second line to the third?

Comment: To go from the first line to the second, they are mapping $k$ into $14-k$. To go from the second line to the third, they are applying the well-known identity $$\sum_{n=1}^{N}n^3 = \left(\frac{N(N+1)}{2}\right)^2 = \left(\sum_{n=1}^{N} n \right)^2. $$

Comment: For the the last equality, it is standard that the sum of the cubes of the first $n$ natural numbers is equal to the sum of these numbers, squared.

Comment: Sorry Jack D'Aurizio how do you mean mapping k into 14-k?

Comment: Do you mean simply subtract 14 from each (14-k)? surely this would have to be compensated for elsewhere? But the rest of the expression remains the same?

Comment: I'm still confused by the first part happy to give the reward to Jack D'Aurizio or anyone else who can clarify what is mean by mapping k into 14-k.